# CakePhp $hasAndBelongsToMany not saving multiple select items as expected

Tags: cakephp, associations, multi-select, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have the following code setup (snipped for brevity)

```
class BasePackage extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'BasePackage';
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('ProductSubtype', 'ProductType');
}

class ProductType extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'ProductType';
}

class ProductSubtype extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'ProductSubtype';    
}
```

Above are the simple Model classes.

```
/*  tables in database  */
base_packages
product_types
product_subtypes
base_packages_product_types
base_packages_product_subtypes
```

The first table is the main package that users are creating with the form, the product_* tables are pre-loaded with appropriate types and subtypes (they don't change very often), the last two are the Join tables that CakePhp wants to have

```
/*  in BasePackage/add.ctp  */
//  ...
<ul class="nwblock">
    <li>
    <?php 
        echo $this->Form->input('ProductType.product_type_id', array(
            'label' => 'Choose Product Type',
            'type'  => 'select',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'style' => 'width:300px; margin-bottom:20px;',
            'options' => $protypes
        ));
    ?>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="nwblock">
    <li>
    <?php 
        echo $this->Form->input('ProductSubtype.product_subtype_id', array(
            'label' => 'Choose Subtype(s)',
            'multiple' => 'multiple',
            'type'  => 'select',
            'class' => 'form-control',
            'style' => 'width:300px;height:390px;margin-bottom:20px;',
            'options' => $subtypes
        ));
    ?>
    </li>
</ul>
//  ...
```

Above we see the two controls that are loaded from the product_* tables.  The types are a single select dropdown and the subtypes are a multiple select list.

```
/*  in BasePackageController.php    */
public function add() {
    $protypes = $this->BasePackage->ProductType->find('list', 
            array('fields' => array('ProductType.id', 'ProductType.display')));
    $subtypes = $this->BasePackage->ProductSubtype->find('list', 
            array('fields' => array('ProductSubtype.id', 'ProductSubtype.display')));
    $this->set('protypes', $protypes);
    $this->set('subtypes', $subtypes);

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->BasePackage->create();           
        if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
            $this->BasePackage->saveAll($this->request->data, array('deep' => true));
        }
    }
}
```

The process is as follows, while the user creates a new BasePackage, they select a ProductType from a  dropdown box and one to many ProductSubtypes from a multiple select list.  When the $this->BasePackage->saveAll() call is made, the data to be inserted into base_packages and base_packages_product_types tables is inserted correctly.  However, the base_packages_product_subtypes table remains untouched.

**UPDATE:**

If I remove the `'multiple' => 'multiple',` from the form->input options, the code saves both the producttype and the productsubtype (as expected).  This is obviously not sufficient, as I need to save 1-to-many.  Anyone know how to activate the 'Many' part of the HABTM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me `BasePackage <> ProductType` looks more like it should be a many-to-one relation, ie `BasePackage belongsTo ProductType`?

Anyways... please follow the conventions as described in the Cookbook:

**http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-habtm**

The form helper should be fed with the model name, ie `ProductSubtype`, and the view var should be camel backed plural, ie `productSubtypes`, that way CakePHP will do the rest for you automatically.

```
public function add() {
    // ...
    $this->set('productSubtypes', $subtypes);
    // ...
}
```

```
echo $this->Form->input('ProductSubtype', array(
    'label' => 'Choose Subtype(s)',
    'class' => 'form-control',
    'style' => 'width:300px;height:390px;margin-bottom:20px;'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with `BasePackage->saveAssociated` ?

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array